# View is not returned

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have this model

```py
class RawMaterialReport(models.Model):
    _name = 'raw.material.report'
    _description = 'Raw Material Report'

    product_id = fields.Many2one(
        'product.product', string='Product',
        required=False,
    )

    @api.multi
    def open_raw_materials(self):
        mrp_productions = self._context.get('active_ids')
        mrp_production = 
        self.env['mrp.production'].browse(mrp_productions)
        raw_products = 
        mrp_production.mapped('move_raw_ids.product_id')
        for p in raw_products:
            self.create({'product_id': p.id})

        view_id = self.env.ref('trk.raw_material_report_tree').id
        view = {
            'name': _('Details'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree, form',
            'res_model': 'raw.material.report',
            'views': [(view_id, 'form')],
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            # 'res_id': self.id,
        }
        return view

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
        <data>

    <record id="raw_material_report_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">raw.material.report.tree</field>
        <field name="model">raw.material.report</field>
        <field name="priority">2</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Sales Orders" >
                <field name="product_id" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>



     <record id="action_raw_material_report" 
            model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">zzzzz</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">raw.material.report</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,form</field>
        </record>


        <record id="action_server_learn_skill" 
            model="ir.actions.server">
            <field name="name">test</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_raw_material_report" />
            <field name="binding_model_id" 
            ref="mrp.model_mrp_production" />
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">model.open_raw_materials()</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="menu_sale_order1"
            name="test"
            action="action_raw_material_report"
            parent="sale.sale_order_menu"
            sequence="2" />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

When I go to action and run my method everything goes good until that point where I try to return a view it just not redirecting me to my tree view. Nothing happens. But `raw.material.report` Records got created and I can check them if I go to my menu, it opens list view with them. So there is some kind of a problem with my return, can someone help on this? I actually tried to return an action like this

```
action = self.env.ref('trk.action_raw_material_report').read()[0]
return action
```

but get the same, it just not redirecting me to my tree view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that in `action_server_learn_skill`

I needed

```
<field name="code">action = model.open_raw_materials()</field>
```

instead of

```
<field name="code">model.open_raw_materials()</field>
```

because the method is not returning anything to action.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 return {
        'name': _('Details'),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree, form',
        'res_model': 'raw.material.report',
        'views': [(view_id_tree[0].id, 'tree'),(False,'form')],
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        # 'res_id': self.id,
        'target': 'current',
    }
```

Issue may be because of passing wrong id in views  [(view_id, 'form')] instead of  [(view_id, 'tree')]

Comment: what is view_id_tree[0]? it's coming from action or? because I don't have this variable in my code.

Comment: @Chaban33 its view_id in your case [(view_id, 'tree')]

Comment: Unfortunately same, problem.

Comment: @Chaban33 Check this http://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2017/10/redirect-to-tree-view-from-button-click.html